# SwiftUI on OS X: How to get source application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am working on an OS X application which gets called by other applications via Custom URL Scheme. Below code allows me to capture the incoming URL successfully. However I also need to get the name or bundle_id of the source application.

This document explains how it is done for UIKit, [Defining Custom URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) , where it mentions `let sendingAppID = options[.sourceApplication]`. How can I do the same on an OS X application ?

EDIT: Found a kind of workaround, first get the pid of the source application using `let pid = event.attributeDescriptor(forKeyword: AEKeyword(keySenderPIDAttr))!.int32Value` then iterate over `workspace.runningApplications` to get `localised_name` or `bundle_id` for the matching pid. Doesn't look very elegant but works. Any better way of doing this ? i.e. getting bundle_id or name directly via event handler ?

```
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        NSAppleEventManager
            .shared()
            .setEventHandler(
                self,
                andSelector: #selector(handleURL(event:reply:)),
                forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass),
                andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL)
            )
        NSLog("Debug: Handle Set")
       
    }
    
    @objc func handleURL(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor, reply: NSAppleEventDescriptor) {
        if let path = event.paramDescriptor(forKeyword: keyDirectObject)?.stringValue?.removingPercentEncoding {
            NSLog("Opened URL: \(path)")
        }
    }
}
```